# Java Swing - Background Image Not Showing

Tags: java, swing, class, windowbuilder

I'm pretty new to Java and am trying to create a program in Swing. Everything works except the background image doesn't show up. The code to add the background image seems to be fine (I got help with that). My main concern is my placement of the BackgroundPanel class and the instance of the class that I called (in main, which is the only place BackgroundPanel is referenced in the main document). I also have a separate document for the BackgroundPanel class itself (both documents pasted below).

Can someone please direct me in the right direction? I took off the import and package info because they were taking up a lot of space on here. Thanks!

Here is my main code:

```
public class InvitationCard extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtMood;
private JPanel panel;
private JTextPane textPaneBody;
private JTextPane textPaneNames;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InvitationCard frame = new InvitationCard();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                BackgroundPanel BP = new BackgroundPanel();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public InvitationCard() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 637, 490);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
Double.MIN_VALUE };
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    panel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc_panel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_panel.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc_panel.gridheight = 5;
    gbc_panel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_panel.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(panel, gbc_panel);
    GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[] { 130, 0 };
    gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[] { 26, 0, 0, 0 };
    gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

    Font font1 = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12);
    Font font2 = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 12);
    Font font3 = new Font("nouradilla.regular", Font.BOLD, 12);
    Font font4 = new Font("GearedSlab-Bold", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    txtMood = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtMood = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtMood.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_txtMood.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc_txtMood.gridx = 0;
    gbc_txtMood.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(txtMood, gbc_txtMood);
    txtMood.setEditable(false);
    txtMood.setText("Mood: ");
    txtMood.setColumns(10);

    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_comboBox.gridx = 0;
    gbc_comboBox.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // get item from dropdown
            String item = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            if (item == "Whimsical") {
                textPaneNames.setFont(font1);
                textPaneBody.setFont(font1);
            } else if (item == "Traditional") {
                textPaneNames.setFont(font2);
                textPaneBody.setFont(font2);
            } else if (item == "Modern") {
                textPaneNames.setFont(font3);
                textPaneBody.setFont(font3);

            } else if (item == "Crazy") {
                textPaneNames.setFont(font4);
                textPaneBody.setFont(font4);

            }

        }

    });

    comboBox.setModel(
            new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Select", "Whimsical",      
"Traditional", "Modern", "Crazy" }));

    textPaneNames = new JTextPane();
    textPaneNames.setText("FIRST1 LAST1\n&\nFIRST2 LAST2");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textPaneNames = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textPaneNames.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textPaneNames.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_textPaneNames.gridx = 3;
    gbc_textPaneNames.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(textPaneNames, gbc_textPaneNames);

    textPaneBody = new JTextPane();
    textPaneBody.setText(
            "REQUEST THE HONOR OF YOUR PRESENCE \nAT THEIR WEDDING 
CEREMONY\n\nFRIDAY, JANUARY SECOND\nTWO-THOUSAND AND SEVENTEEN\nSIX-THIRTY IN 
THE EVENING\n\nADDRESS GOES HERE\n903 ADDRESS LANE\nCITY, STATE\n\n\nRECEPTION 
TO FOLLOW");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textPaneBody = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textPaneBody.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_textPaneBody.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textPaneBody.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_textPaneBody.gridx = 3;
    gbc_textPaneBody.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(textPaneBody, gbc_textPaneBody);

    // centers the names and body text
    StyledDocument doc = textPaneBody.getStyledDocument();
    StyledDocument doc2 = textPaneNames.getStyledDocument();

    SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

    doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
    doc2.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc2.getLength(), center, false);
 }

}
```

//And here is BackgroundPanel.java:

```
public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

  Image image;
  public BackgroundPanel()
  {
    try
    {
      image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new  
java.net.URL(getClass().getResource("/satin.jpg"), "/satin.jpg"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) { /*handled in paintComponent()*/ }
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    if (image != null)
      g.drawImage(image, 0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
  }
```

}

Comment: You do nothing with the `BackgroundPanel` you created... At least, add it to the GUI hierarchy!

Comment: `new  java.net.URL(getClass().getResource("/satin.jpg"), "/satin.jpg")` The image is located at `/satin.jpg/satin.jpg`?!? I ask because `satin.jpg` is a strange name for a directory..

Comment: @jean-baptisteyunes I'm a bit new to Java. I added some BackgroundPanel info to main. Would I add more or other code under the "public InvitationCard()" constructor? (I'm assuming it's a constructor).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes satin.jpg is the file I'm trying to set as the background right now. Full directory would be img/satin/jpg but I've noticed that just the name of the image seems to work in another program of mine.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Okay actually I understand now I have to add the information to the frame. Thank you!

Comment: *"Full directory would be img/satin/jpg"* I can only guess you mean Full `img/satin.jpg` (look carefully for the difference between those two strings). Note that neither is equvalent to what the code is saying, which would result in `/satin.jpg/satin.jpg` with ***both*** a `satin.jpg` filename **and a** `satin.jpg` parent directory. It seems to me you have little or no idea what you are doing, programming does not work by magic, there is a logic to it that you are missing..

Comment: I've mentioned I'm a beginner so yes there are things I'm going to miss. No need to get snarky. Thanks for pointing out the different though. It's really helpful for beginners like me who do believe in magic.

Answer (score 1):

Add this right after `BackgroundPanel BP = new BackgroundPanel();` in your main():

```
frame.add(BP);
```

You need to add your component to your frame. Otherwise methods like paint() won't be called.

Comment: Thanks I will try out both things!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... let's see
Rewriting BackgroundPanel with only just a few modifications, I should have this

```
public class BackgroundPanel extends JComponent {
    //every code you put in this class
}
```

this should enable you to do this if I am correct

```
setContentPane(new BackgroundPanel());
```

If this doesn't work, please tell me so I can be of better service.

**Edit**

Going through your code again I think this is what you'd have to do

```
public InvitationCard(){
    setContentPane(new BackgroundPanel());
    /* then every other code follows,
       except the "setContentPane(contentPane)"
       you can comment that out
    */

    this.add(contentPane);
}
```

And also your BackgroundPanel class can still remain a sub-class of JPanel, it is better that way

There would be no need for`frame.add(BP);`anymore.

Since I don't have a means to run it now, I still don't know if this solves your problem... You tell me

Comment: I added that to my code under (constructor?) InvitationCard() but it just makes everything go gray. I tried this both while commenting out "setContentPane(contentPane);" and while it was uncommented. I also added "frame.add(BP);" in main and nothing happened with that :-/. Please let me know if you have any more thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: Oh also was the "extends JComponent" intentional? It brings a lot many errors if I change it to JComponent from JPanel.

Comment: Unfortunately the background image is still not working. I even changed a line in the BackgroundPanel class that I thought might be problematic (image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/satin.jpg"));) but the image still does not show. Not sure what I'm missing still.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit too late, but I think you may need to set your BackgroundPanel Opaque boolean to true.

```
    BackgroundPanel BP = new BackgroundPanel();
    BP.setOpaque(true);
```

You will likely need to do this with any area that you want to have a "background" color or image.